# 2007 Mercury Mountaineer won't shift automatically, able to drive on manual gear 1 only

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting

I was on the way to work this morning when I suddenly noticed that my car (automatic transmission) won't shift up from the first gear anymore. This also happened a few weeks ago and, thinking it may have been a computer issue, I just restarted the engine and I was able to continue driving normally after. However, that didn't work this time.

All gears R, D, 2, and 3 don't work - except for gear 1 which, fortunately, allowed me to drive back home albeit slowly. It takes a while to shift to gear 1 from P, however, and it usually causes the car to jerk forward.

What could be the issue of my car? As there are no auto repair shops open here right now due to the virus issue, is there something I can do by myself?

Comment: Nothing you can do but wait for a transmission shop to open.

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level? That would be my first step. Or, get the level checked...

Comment: COuld the car have gone into limp home mode - can you check for error codes?

Comment: There is a computer system in your car that gives On-Board Diagnostics (OBD) codes, these can be read by a special reader, you can buy basic bluetooth ones for little money or get your codes read at an auto parts store for free. I'd get these read or read them yourself to see if there's anything revealing. Also check your transmission fluid level using the method specified in your manual.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do any of those. Also, my car doesn't have a dipstick for the transmission fluid - I think the only way to check the level is to take a look under. I'll try taking it to an oil change shop for a quick check if the nearby ones are open.

Comment: This is why I don't like dipstickless trannys. The first step to do when transmission problems occurr is to confirm levels are good. If you have any transmission stains under you vehicle, it would indicate you may have low fluid levels. The more you drive with low fluid, the more damage is being done. You might consider towing it to a tranny shop to have it checked out.

Comment: Yes, it would have been easy to check if it had a dipstick. I never noticed any stains of any type underneath my vehicle so the fluid level was not the first thing that came into mind but I'll get that checked if I am able. Sadly, the quarantine is not making it easy to move around.